# Cannot get ExecuteScriptAsync() to work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, cefsharp

I'm trying to set a HTML input to read-only using ExecuteScriptAsync. I can make it work, but it's not an ideal scenario, so I'm wondering if anyone knows why it doesn't work the way I would expect it to.
I'm using Cef3, version 63.

I tried to see if it's a timing issue and doesn't appear to be.
I tried invalidating the view of the browser but that doesn't seem to help.

The code I currently have, which works:

```
public void SetReadOnly()
{
    var script = @"
        (function(){
        var labelTags = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
        var searchingText = 'Notification Initiator';
        var found;
        for (var i=0; i<labelTags.length; i++)
        {
            if(labelTags[i].textContent == searchingText)
            {
                found = labelTags[i]
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found)
        {
            found.innerHTML='Notification Initiator (Automatic)';
            var input;
            input = found.nextElementSibling;
            if(input)
            {
                input.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
            }

        }})()
        ";
        _viewer.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        _viewer.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
}
```

now, if I remove

```
found.innerHTML='Notification Initiator (Automatic)';
```

the input is no longer shown as read-only. The HTML source of the loaded webpage does show it as read-only, but it seems like the frame doesn't get re-rendered once that property is set.

Another issue is that I'm executing the script twice. If I run it only once I don't get the desired result. I'm thinking this could be a problem with V8 Context that is required for the script to run. Apparently running the script will create the context, so that could be the reason why running it twice works.

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, haven't found anything that would explain this weird behaviour. Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please confirm you have read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript both your execute calls do exactly the same thing, they're both executing on the main frame,  look at the source if you don't believe me. Executing on the UI thread is not required. You should wrap your script in an anonymous closure as it's executed in the global context. You can use Devtools for debugging see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have removed the UI thread call and wrapped the script as per your suggestions. I have also now read the document, and for me it seems like my problem is V8 context. The thing is, I need to run my JS after some other script was ran on the website, and I don't think that creates context. I have tried adding a RenderProcessMessageHandler and running the script on ContextCreated, but that didn't work.

Comment: @amaitland You are right regarding both execute calls doing the exact same thing, that was also in the document you linked. What I think is happening, I'm creating V8 Context on the first call " it's possible to create a V8Context using IFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync". I would debug but I can't spend much more time on this, since it already "works"... Thanks for your help!